# A way to query service fabric from within a running node

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The idea is to add some metadata into App Insights about a running service fabric app via a custom App insights initializer.  I want to be able to instrument what app/node is running the instance of my service.

Maybe SF already does this but my app insights health monitor is only showing custom events that I specifically wrote and nothing extra added by default.  I'd like to add to my custom events and know a bit about the SF app/node so I can debug more effectively once SF is released and we start to scale out reliable services.

noob to this forum so please be kind :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have not explicitly tried it yet from inside an actor or SF service, but telemetry client (app insights) can be called in any console app. Just post your new events, exceptions, metrics as normal. They take some time to show up in AI. As an architecture idea, I might create a common logger actor as an aggregator. This way, all the actors in your app just speak to "actors" in the simple actor-to-actor stack and you don't have to take a dependency on another framework and api inside your logging consumers; keeping things clean and abstracted. The logging actor can be stateless or stateful and using a "write-behind" design to keep things moving. It also means you abstract the perf logging and can change the implementation at one place - inside the logging actor.  Maybe you want to change logging down the road to also log to a db store, or also email or text some events, or even change from AI for some reason. Then all your logging "consumer" clients don't change and don't know.

Comment: I think the app insights implementation on Service Fabric is not registering the same default telemetry modules as ASP.net.  The logging idea is a good one to keep it clean.  Generates a new questions though about when to use logger type service and when to use AI.  There is quite some overlap in the capabilities especially around trace.